# How to split train/test of extreme sparse dataset of recommender system?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, svd, collaborative-filtering

I'm using CF algorithm(SVD) on a real world data set. Now I meet a problem about the data sparse problem. That means the sparsity of the user/item rating matrix is around 0.01%. I split the data into train/test set with 80/20, I find that there're just a few users and items in testing set appear in the training set, so I can just use a few rating in testing set to calculate RMSE. Would you give me some advise to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of recommender systems one usually splits each user's history into train and test. More detailed:

1. For each user we write out items he interacted with.
2. Preferably, we order them by (incresing) time to overcome "time-traveling issue" (user can revisit already known items, so you don't want to test on early dataset).
3. As usual, you use first (1-k) percents of your dataset as a train set and the rest as a test set.

Comment: thank you for answer. Do you mean I should reorganize data as:{u1:[v11,v12...],u2:[v21,v22,..],...} and use first (1-k) percents of each user's item list. If so, in my data, to many users rate one item, so if I split them into test set, I will get nothing(the latent factor vec p_u or q_i) to predict the rating of user in test set.

Comment: @littlekid, these users who only interacted with one item are too noisy, I doubt you can get reliable recommendations for them. These users are usually filtered out in preprocessing stage.

Comment: My data sets have devided with different genres, every record not only include vote but review, I think this is the reason that the vote matrix so sparse. If I filter this noisy data, data set will be too small to get recommendations

Comment: I have tried to filter the noisy data you said, and I lose about 2/3 data. Should I just use these remainder to do recommendation?

Comment: It depends on your goals. If you want to roll out production-ready system, then look at how many users and items you have left after filtering. If there are too little of them, it's not an option and I don't really know what to suggest. If there are somewhat many of them (even if less than a half) and you can assume other users will generate more data soon, you can go with that amount. If your interests are purely academic and you just want to play with recommendation systems, then you try whatever approach you like :-)